# UIGestureRecognizer initWithTarget set to object of class id (UIViewController) results in compiler warning for undeclared action selector

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a `UIGestureRecognizer` and setting it's target to a parent `UIViewController`. Xcode warns me that the action selector is undeclared.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.traverseResponderChainforUIViewController action:@selector(handleTap:)];

Warning: Undeclared selector 'handleTap:'
```

It's probably also worth documenting that my `traverseResponderChainforUIViewController` method returns id (though the implementation should ultimately return something that `isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class] or nil`):

```
- (id)traverseResponderChainforUIViewController;
```

Finally...this works perfectly at runtime because the selector is in fact declared in the target `UIViewController` object.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"%@", recognizer.description);
}
```

What can I do to make the compiler happy here?

I'd prefer not to change the architecture of my program (action sent from the view to the view controller), but am I *doing it wrong* (TM) or am I just missing a step of a completely proper implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
YourViewControllerClass *vc = (YourViewControllerClass *)self.traverseResponderChainforUIViewController;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:vc action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but is handleTap defined in your ViewController's public interface?

Comment: That...kind of works. It still feels kind of janky (although I'm being subjective) - you still need to import the UIViewController header file into the UIView where the UIGestureRecognizer is init-ed for the compiler to recognize the method even in the public interface.
I may try to resolve this with a protocol later (pretty sure I could do that by creating an object of id that implements a protocol with the handleTap method), but that's overcomplicated for right now.

Comment: @MattMalesky how can this: self.traverseResponderChainforUIViewController be a method call?